# Struts2 + Hibernate Combination

Tags: hibernate, web-applications, jakarta-ee, struts2

Im going to develop a web application in Struts2 with Hibernate.But im having some questions in my mind

1. Can it possible to **develop quickly** from the base(from the starting level)?
2. **Speed** of the system in the end?
3. **Reusable** code?
4. Usage of **client side codes** is easy?.

May be this is stupid question for the Java EE legends.But i need some idea about this before development.

Answer (score 0):

Well not a very generic Question.But here are quick inputs.

1. It dependents upon how much you know about Java/JSP and in general Servelets.
2. You need time to learn Stuts2 or any other framework basics nuts and bolts.
3. Speed dependents upon may factors like you overall system architecture nature of your application etc.So its like very early to say anything about speed.
4. What you mean by reusable code?
5. Client side i am assuming JavaScript based framework so Stuts2 as an MVC platform is capable enough to get integrated with any java-script framework.